# How display images layer by layer in java

Tags: java, image

I am creating a breakout game and I'm trying to build the brick class which displays an image of a brick layer by layer. But my code compiles but nothing shows up.

This is what I have so far.

Main Class:

```
public class Breakout extends Applet implements Runnable{
Thread thread = new Thread(this);
boolean running = true;
Brick b;
Image dbImage;
Graphics dbg;
public void init(){
    setSize(800,600);
    b = new Brick();
}
public void start(){
    thread.start();
}
public void destroy(){
    running = false;
}
public void stop(){
    running = false;
}
public void run(){
    while(running){
        b.update(this);
        repaint();
        try{
            thread.sleep(20);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("AN ERROR HAS OCCURED");
        }
    }
}
public void update(Graphics g){
    dbImage = createImage(getWidth(),getHeight());
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paint(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImage,0,0,this);
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    b.paint(g,this);
}   

}
```

This is the brick class:

```
public class Brick {
private URL url;
private Image brick;
 Image [][] bricks = new Image[50][3];
public void brick (Breakout bR){
    url = bR.getDocumentBase();
    brick = bR.getImage(url,"brick.png"); 
    for(int i =0; i < bricks.length; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < bricks[0].length; j++)
        bricks[i][j] = brick;

}

public void update(Breakout bR){

}

public void paint(Graphics g, Breakout bR){

    int imageWidth = bricks[0][0].getWidth(bR);
    int imageHeight = bricks[0][0].getHeight(bR);
    for (int i = 0; i < bricks.length; i++)
        for ( int j =0; j < bricks[0].length; j++)

            g.drawImage(bricks[i][j], i * imageWidth + 5, j * imageHeight + 5, bR);

}
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
 b = new Brick();
```

you are calling to create an object but that constructor doesnt exist so it is assume to be the basic default one.

while you have

```
public void brick (Breakout bR){
```

this is some method. not a constructor

change to

```
public Brick (Breakout bR){
```

and

```
b=new Brick(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Graphics area is smaller than you think.

Lets add some basic debug code to pinpoint the issue:

```
public void update(Graphics g){
    dbImage = createImage(getWidth(),getHeight());
    //New line:
    System.out.println("dbImage widthxheight = "+dbImage.getWidth()+"x"+dbImage.getHeight());
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paint(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImage,0,0,this);
}
```

And:

```
public void paint(Graphics g, Breakout bR){

    //New line:
    Rectangle bounds = ((Graphics2D)g).getDeviceConfiguration().getBounds();
    //New line:
    System.out.println("bounds widthxheight = "+bounds.getWidth()+"x"+bounds.getHeight());
    int imageWidth = bricks[0][0].getWidth(bR);
    int imageHeight = bricks[0][0].getHeight(bR);
    //New line:
    System.out.println("imageSize widthxheight = "+imageWidth +"x"+imageHeight);
    for (int i = 0; i < bricks.length; i++)
        for ( int j =0; j < bricks[0].length; j++)

            g.drawImage(bricks[i][j], i * imageWidth + 5, j * imageHeight + 5, bR);
}
```

Now how big is your graphics area according to the console?

Edit: if you don't see any messages at all then your code is not being called and you may need to revise how you start your applet.

Answer (score -1):

You have no main method in Breakout.java. At least one class in a project needs a main method to execute it. You also need to call Thread.start() for your run method to execute on the Thread. Look at [this](http://www.java-examples.com/create-new-thread-using-runnable-example) as an example.

Comment: Applets don't need a main method